# How to determine the expectation of the square of a binomial collection

Tags: statistics, expectation, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to find how to express the expectation of the square of a collection of binomial measurements. If we have a collection:

$$A = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n$$

The expectation of $A$ is the sum of the expectations of each term of $A$. However, for the square of $A$, I'm getting stuck on how $np +(n^2-n)p^2$ is derived. Without any background in number theory, I'm trying to find it as follows, assuming a set of three trials in $A$:

$$E(A^2) = E((a_1 + a_2 + a_3)(a_1 + a_2 + a_3))$$
$$E(A^2) = E(a_1a_1 + a_1a_2 + a_1a_3 + a_2a_1 + a_2a_2 + a_2a_3 + a_3a_1 + a_3a_2 + a_3a_3)$$
$$E(A^2) = E(a_1a_1 + a_2a_2 + a_3a_3)+ 2 E(a_1a_2 + a_1a_3 + a_2a_3))$$

...and from here it grinds to a halt. I am not sure how to evaluate these pairings, and what happens to the probabilities in each. For the final product, I get the idea that in squaring we have $n=3$ that are equal, and the remaining being the entire square of values minus these, which would be $n^2-n = 6$, but then how the probabilities are handled is not making sense. I'm not sure why the $n^2-n$ term has a squared probability when the first one has no square.

I'm hoping someone can explain this in basic terms.

Comment: Assuming independence, you have $E(a_i a_j)=E(a_i) E(a_j)$ when $i \neq j.$   I also assume you know what $E((a_i)^2)$ is.

Comment: @mattbiesecker, yes indeed! My hangup was having blanked on the idea and application of independence for the different samples in the binomial. This was having me convolute $a_ia_i$ and $a_ia_j$, and see them as the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $a_i$ are **Bernoulli** random variables, $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$. Let us work with your concrete $n=3$ example.

Note that if $i\ne j$, then by independence $E(a_ia_j)=E(a_i)E(a_j)=p^2$.

As to the $a_i^2$, note that $a_i^2=a_i$, so $E(a_i^2)=p$.

Thus in your example we get
$$E(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2=3p +6p^2.$$
This is consistent with the formula $E((a_1+\cdots+a_n)^2)=np+(n^2-n)p^2$. The same argument will work in general.

Comment: *smacks head*....Oh man....I've been at this for ages and didn't even think of seeing the different $a_i$ and $a_j$ as similar to independent marginal distributions of a joint distribution, in which the joint distribution is just the two margins multiplied together. Perhaps thats not the best way to think about it, but its the logic that makes sense to me.

Comment: The idea can be used even when the $a_i$ are not independent, as in the case when we are sampling without replacement from a lot of size $m$ that has $k$ defectives. But in that case the $E(a_ia_j)$ takes a bit more work to compute.