# Covariance of sums of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, independence, covariance, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$ are independent Bernoulli random variables, with $X_i \sim Bern(\theta)$, $Y_i \sim Bern(\eta)$, $Z_i \sim Bern(\pi)$, where $\theta, \eta, \pi \in (0, 1)$. Define $S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i$, $U = \sum_{i=1}^n X_iZ_i$

Find $Cov(S, T)$ and $Cov(T, U)$.

$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - E(S)E(T)$$

$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i)$$

$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i)\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_iY_i)$$

$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - \sum_{i=1}^n \theta\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i)E(Y_i)$$

$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - \sum_{i=1}^n \theta\sum_{i=1}^n \theta\eta$$
$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - n\theta n\theta\eta$$
$$Cov(S, T) = E(ST) - n^2\theta^2\eta$$

I'm struggling to calculate E(ST) and I'm not sure if my thought process for calculating E(S) and E(T) is correct. Any advice? I'm assuming the same approach can be taken to find Cov(T, U).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write out $ST$ as a double sum:
$$ST = \left(\sum_i X_i \right)\left(\sum_j X_jY_j\right) = \sum_i \sum_j X_iX_jY_j$$
where both $i$ and $j$ range from $1$ to $n$. You will need to consider the case $i=j$ separately from the case $i\ne j$, because the variables $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent only when $i\ne j$. When $i=j$ you have $X_i^2$, whose expectation you can deduce from $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$ and $E(X_i)$. (Meanwhile, $Y_j$ is independent of any combination of $X$'s.)

You can handle $TU$ similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far but I'm still a little confused. At this point I get $E(ST) = E(\sum_i \sum_j X_i X_j Y_j) = \sum_i \sum_j E(X_i X_j Y_j) = \sum_i \sum_j E(X_i X_j)E(Y_j)$. I'm not too sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: @Pierre If $i$ and $j$ are different then you can write $E(X_iX_j)=E(X_i)E(X_j)$ by independence, then plug in $E(X_i)$ and $E(X_j)$. If $i$ and $j$ are the same then you must find $E(X_i^2)$.

Comment: @Pierre Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1274948/215011 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4382394/215011

Comment: That helped out a lot, thanks!